# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'De index ligt buiten de matrixgrenzen.' while datalezer.getvalue(1) does have value

Tags: vb.net, oledb

When I run the query I get 2 results, I want to pass the results to the text boxes. When I run the `datalezer.getvalue(0)` it works fine, but when I run `datalezer.getvalue(1)` it says:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: The index is outside the matrix limits.

Can someone help me?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Overspanningsinterval As String = ""
    Dim overspanning As Double = TextBox1.Text 'overspanning'
    Dim oversapnningvereenvoud As Double = overspanning / 1000 'delen van de overspanning in tientallen'


    If oversapnningvereenvoud <= 5 Then RadioButton1.Checked = True : Overspanningsinterval = "[0-5]"
    If oversapnningvereenvoud > 5 And oversapnningvereenvoud <= 10 Then RadioButton2.Checked = True : Overspanningsinterval = "[5-10]"
    If oversapnningvereenvoud > 10 And oversapnningvereenvoud <= 15 Then RadioButton3.Checked = True : Overspanningsinterval = "[10-15]"
    If oversapnningvereenvoud > 15 Then RadioButton4.Checked = True : Overspanningsinterval = "[15-20]"


    verbinding.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Dim command1 As New OleDbCommand

    Query = "Select vloer from " & Overspanningsinterval & " "
    command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    command1.CommandText = Query
    command1.Connection = verbinding

    Dim datalezer As OleDbDataReader = command1.ExecuteReader
    datalezer.Read()
    TextBox2.Text = datalezer.GetValue(0)
    TextBox2.Text = datalezer.GetValue(1)
    datalezer.Close()

    verbinding.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: There's only one column/field in your dataset...

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the value from *ROW* 2? You are trying to get the value from COLUMN 2 as @TimWilliams noted, which doesn't exist (you have only one column `vloer`). Otherwise you will need a second column in your SQL query to assign to the 2nd value by extracting it from a second DataRow.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help , I appreciate it a lot. With the help I can now show both results :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggested...

```
Dim datalezer As OleDbDataReader = command1.ExecuteReader
datalezer.Read()
TextBox2.Text = datalezer.GetValue(0)
datalezer.Read()
TextBox2.Text = datalezer.GetValue(0)
datalezer.Close()
```